# C# Windows forma, transparencia de label sobre otras herramientas

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2019

estoy haciendo un odontograma en el cual represente cada diente con 5 botones que hacen las veces de caras de los diente, ahora necesito poner por encima un label con fondo transparente y solo una X por encima, simulando un diente tachado.
Y no encontré la forma de que ese label se transparente, me aparece con fondo solido y no me deja ver el diente debajo.

Si alguien me ayuda, se lo agradezco, saludos Carlos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi es como se ve, debajo del numero 18 hay un grupo de botones como en el caso del numero 17, que una vez tapado con el label y con el codigo que me paso Yusef, sigue sin notarse la transparencia

Answer (score 0):

El `label` acepta transparencia, pero de una forma extraña. Realmente toma el color del contenedor padre. Un `button` no es un contenedor, por lo que desde el diseñador no podrás asignar el botón como padre del label, pero si puedes hacerlo por código

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    label1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    SeTParent(button1, label1);
}
private void SeTParent(Control parent, Control child)
{
    var pos = child.Parent.PointToScreen(child.Location);
    pos = parent.PointToClient(pos);
    child.Parent = parent;
    child.Location = pos;
}
```

Comment: Hola yussef gracias por tu respuesta, el tema es que tengo 5 botones dentro de un groupbox, estos botones están separados y necesito cubrirlos con un label transparente que va a tener una X simulando que estos 5 botones están tachados. La pregunta es si esto se puede hacer?

Comment: @carlos hasta donde entiendo tu problema se resuelve con el código de mi respuesta (que está probado y funciona). Tu probaste usarlo?

Comment: No me funciona, recien lo probe y sigue sin mostrarme el boton que esta debajo, ahora veo si te puedo subir un print